# Using variables to shorten cmd script length

Tags: windows, cmd

This is my first attempt at scripting in the windows command line. I am trying to use variables to make the commands that I am going to write easier to read. Unfortunately I can't get the script to work properly, and Pause_ is not keeping the cmd window open so that I might see what is going wrong. Below is the script I have written so far.

```
@echo off
:: Script for generating java classes from xsd using jibx
:: 
:: Create variables for the different paths for easy editing later
set jibx = ../../Libraries/jibx/lib/jibx-tools.jar
set CodeGen = org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen
set package = src/com/TersoSolutions/Jetstream/SDK/
set source = resources/xsd/
set binding = resources/bindings/
::
::
:: First Command 
java -cp %jibx% %CodeGen% -b %binding%GetConfigurationResponse.xml -p %package%Application/Model/GetConfigurationResponse %source%Application/1.1/GetConfigurationResponse.xsd 
::
:: Repeat the command  
java -cp %jibx% %CodeGen% -b %binding%GetConfigurationResponse2.xml -p %package%Application/Model/GetConfigurationResponse2 %source%Application/1.1/GetConfigurationResponse.xsd 
::
Pause_
```

The intent was to repeat the command in a similar manner to verify that I will be able to write the script in a way where I can list all the operations that I need to accomplish.

EDIT:

The command I am trying to replicate in the script works directly in the command line as follows

```
java -cp ../../Libraries/jibx/lib/jibx-tools.jar org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen -b /resources/bindings/GetConfigurationResponse.xml -p com.TersoSolutions.JetStream.SDK.Application.Model.GetConfigurationResponse /resources/xsd/Applicationi/1.1/GetConfigurationResponse.xsd
```

Comment: What is Pause_ ? Open cmd.exe and then run your script to see the error, probably, Pause_ unrecognized.

Comment: Pause shouldn't have the _ after it, this was a mistake in a tutorial I was following

Comment: No, there is still a problem where the script will not accept the variables as paths to the respective elements. Although the script does pause now and gives me the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `Pause_` should be `Pause`.

Secondly, `Set` command should not be used with spaces.

To debug your snippet, try to `echo` your variables after setting them:

```
set binding = resources/bindings/
echo binding
>>>%binding%

set binding=resources/bindings/
echo binding
>>>resources/bindings/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
:: Script for generating java classes from xsd using jibx
:: 
:: Create variables for the different paths for easy editing later
set "jibx=../../Libraries/jibx/lib/jibx-tools.jar"
set "CodeGen=org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen"
set "package=com.TersoSolutions.JetStream.SDK."
set "source=/resources/xsd/"
set "binding=/resources/bindings/"
::
::
:: First Command 
java -cp %jibx% %CodeGen% -b %binding%GetConfigurationResponse.xml -p %package%Application/Model/GetConfigurationResponse %source%Application/1.1/GetConfigurationResponse.xsd
:: Repeat the command  
java -cp %jibx% %CodeGen% -b %binding%GetConfigurationResponse.xml -p %package%Application/Model/GetConfigurationResponse %source%Application/1.1/GetConfigurationResponse.xsd
Pause
```